# unable to perform apt update

Tags: apt

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::16). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Force the use of IPv4 - you don't have v6 available.

Comment: It's right there in your output: `101: Network is unreachable`. Fix your network connection. Then apt will work.